# How To Change A Label Class In Django Crispy Forms

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am wanting to create a bootstrap themed togglebox with crispy forms, but the toggle box displays with a checkbox inside it.

In order to find out why I opened the page in Chrome and using inspect, deleted the class from the label tag (`custom-control-label` below) which removed the inner checkbox leaving just the bootstrap togglebox as I wanted.

So my question is how can I remove a class from a cripsy forms field?

forms.py

```
completed = forms.BooleanField(label='Have you completed it?', required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={}))
```

generated html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="div_id_completed" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="completed" class="checkboxinput custom-control-input" 
         id="id_completed" checked="">
        <label for="id_completed" class="custom-control-label"> 
            Have you completed it
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not override it for a checkbox in a custom css file?

Comment: When I've tried overriding things in custom templates before I cannot get them working properly as I dont know how to access attributes. I know how to access field.label and field.id_for_label , but thats it. I made my own custom template the other day and couldnt figure out how to access the key/value fields in a MultipleChoiceField for example